# .slideDown() content below jumps (isn't fluid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm writing a simple page that I want to be able to slide some content down when a button is clicked. Unfortunately this also causes some issues with the button I have underneath the sliding content. When I click the first button to slide content down, it works fine. As soon as I click the 2nd button, it slides the first content up, and the 2nd down and causes some jumping with the button below.

```
$('#1G').live('click', function(){
$('#slv').slideUp('slow');
$('#gld').slideUp('slow');
$('#brz').slideToggle('slow');

});

$('#2G').live('click', function(){
$('#brz').slideUp('slow');
$('#gld').slideUp('slow');
$('#slv').slideToggle('slow');

});

$('#3G').live('click', function(){
$('#brz').slideUp('slow');
$('#slv').slideUp('slow');
$('#gld').slideToggle('slow');

});
```

This happens on what seems to be every animation of size.

Here's an example: 
http://kod.singaming.net/hosting

I've tried adding a width on #brz #slv and #gld, and I've tried adding a height to each.

Is it some css property I have to set? Let me know if I need to explain anything else.

Comment: Is this affecting a particular browser?  It appears quite smooth in my testing

Comment: It seems to be affecting Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE8

Comment: Also, sometimes the new content slides up and over the old content, and sometimes the old content slides down to reveal the clicked content... in the case where the content div is already visible.

Comment: I have a theory that this problem comes from the fact that adjacent margins collapse, but I have yet to test it.

Comment: has this been solved? The example doesn't look jumpy to me.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal: It appears he is using a version of my solution but has not marked the questions answered yet.

Comment: Okay! Just a note: It appears that this (relatively common) bug has to do with (as I suspected) margins collapsing. While the element is "sliding", the margins do not collapse, but when it is finished, it does. Some well-placed padding or removal of margins would also likely solve the issue.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal: nice detective work. There were initially a few more things wrong that were causing the sliding of the divs to happen improperly, but your comment would certainly remedy the "jumpiness" of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new method uses one box called `info` into which the correct content is loaded using the `.load()` function.

alternative html:

```
<div id="info" class='pkg'></div> 
<div id="button" class="clearfix">
```

alternative script:

```
$('#1G').live('click', function(){
    if ($("#info").hasClass("1")) return false;
    $('#info').removeClass("1 2 3").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('_packages/bronze.html')
    }).slideToggle('slow').addClass("1");
});

$('#2G').live('click', function(){
    if ($("#info").hasClass("2")) return false;
    $('#info').removeClass("1 2 3").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('_packages/silver.html')
    }).slideToggle('slow').addClass("2");
});

$('#3G').live('click', function(){
    if ($("#info").hasClass("3")) return false;
    $('#info').removeClass("1 2 3").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('_packages/gold.html')
    }).slideToggle('slow').addClass("3");
});
```

css for `style.css`:

```
#info {
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
height: 120px;
}
```

some other script that changes:

```
$('#brz').load('_packages/bronze.html');
$('#slv').load('_packages/silver.html');
$('#gld').load('_packages/gold.html');
```

The above can all just go away.

### EDIT

I added the code I mentioned in my comment to prevent the buttons from functioning if the click is on the currently selected item. It's probably not the most elegant solution but it works. I add the class `1`, `2`, or `3` depending on the item clicked, and remove all of them upon a click of a different one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to try a different method.

Comment: @MoDFox: I fixed it and tested it. the above solution does precisely what you desire.

Comment: you should also consider adding a marker to keep track of the currently selected item so that if someone selected 1GB and then selected it again it would not hide and reshow, it would just remain. I will add this to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the 3 divs `#brz`, `#slv`, and `#gld` are not wrapped in a `div` that will prevent the button below from moving because it is always the same height regardless of the movement of the content inside of it.

try:

```
<div style="[some height]">
     // your three content divs
    <div id="brz"></div> 
    <div id="slv"></div> 
    <div id="gld"></div> 
</div>
```

the `[some height]` should be equal to whatever height you need it to be so that it will not be affected by the changes of the content inside the div.

Comment: The problem with that is it leaves a huge gap, I want it to do what slideDown intends, slide down the content underneath.

Comment: I have another idea. Would it be desired that upon click on any package it hides the current content with a slideUP then shows the just selected content with a slideDown?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.